# Python keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python

Sorry for the basic question, the first time I've used python as I need it for something specific.

I'm using the docx-mailmerge 0.5.0 library which works great for replacing mailmerge tags in word.

However, some of the tags in word are like this test_Tag[1,1,0,0].

It appears as though the full string has to be used to replace the tag, so I can't use "test_Tag" I have to use "test_Tag[1,1,0,0]" the problem is the library works like this to merge the fields:

```
document.merge(
    mergeFieldName = "Value To Replace With"
)
```

so if the field was just "test_Tag":

```
document.merge(
    test_Tag = "Value To Replace With"
)
```

works fine, but I can't use :

```
document.merge(
    test_Tag[1,1,0,0] = "Value To Replace With"
)
```

Which is obvious! I get "keyword can't be an expression" - so how would i go about doing this? I need to be able to push through the tag names in a loop from an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is ugly, but it should work:

```
document.merge(
    **{"test_Tag[1,1,0,0]":"Value To Replace With"}
)
```

Comment: The error is gone, thanks! However, the library isn't replacing the tag, it's just producing an empty area. It's a bit frustrating because the library is showing one of the fields in the console as owner_GroupName[0,1,1,1,1] but if i do **{"owner_GroupName[0,1,1,1,1]":"Value To Replace With"} the new word document doesn't replace the merge field it's just blank. Working with word documents is a nightmare!

Comment: Actually while the error is gone, i don't think document.merge is recognising this as it's not even replacing a basic one, such as "TestField" with **{"TestField":"Replacement"} isn't being replaced, while if i use TestField="Replacement" it does get replaced

Comment: @GlenElkins don't know what to tell you. This sounds like a library specific issue, so you are going to have to add some more info

Comment: Actually, it does seem to work! I misstyped ha. Thanks !